# Reading SAML or Shibboleth header in nodejs

Tags: node.js, apache, http-headers, saml-2.0

I have a URL, say xyz.com, which upon being hit sends a request to Apache HTTP server which redirects to a come login page.

Upon sucessful verification of user the Apache redirects to my nodejs application with URL xyz.com
With SAML header which contains user info.

How to read this SAML header in node js.

PS: Had it been a Java application instead of nodejs req.getSession would have worked.

Thanks

Comment: How are you communicating between Node.js and Apache? Are you using Passenger, or proxying requests into Node?  I've been over [this bug report](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1479) with Passenger developers about the fact that it doesn't allow per-request environment variables in to work correctly. You must configure your Shibboleth SP to use HTTP headers instead of environment variables for shibboleth attributes, and read from the Node.js request headers.

Comment: See also [Does Node.js expose per HTTP request environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792326/does-node-js-expose-per-http-request-environment-variables)?

Comment: Our application URL has been configured in Apache as redirect URL where we are redirected after shiboleth authentication. After having redirected how to get the SAML attributes from the request header

Comment: Got it ... req.headers had all the value I was looking for